# Tuple with pair and uses-allocator construction

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator, uses-allocator

[`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) support [uses-allocator construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction), while pairs are a kind of corner case with a special treatment that makes them work *as-if* they supported uses-allocator construction.
However, imagine to combine them in a container like:

```cpp
std::vector<std::tuple<std::pair<T, U>, another_type>> vec{};
```

Quite a nonsense type that is good enough for the purpose of the question though.
In this case, the vector forwards the allocator to the tuple as expected (`uses_allocator` is specialized for tuples). However, the tuple only forwards the same allocator to the types for which `uses_allocator_v` is true and this isn't true for pairs.
Therefore, this combination *breaks* the assumption that a pair works *as-if* it supported uses-allocator construction.
Unfortunately, an `std::pair<T, std::pair<U, V>>` suffers from the same problem from what I can tell.

Is there any way to get around this *issue* and make the container above (or more likely something similar that still contains a pair and a second value) work as expected?

Comment: As you cannot change `std::pair`, I don't see a way. Else `template <typename T1, typename T2> using MyPair = std::tuple<T1, T2>;`...

Comment: I'd also be fine with an user-defined class. Though, I want to avoid aligned storage and whatnot while I don't know if I can make it work with an homemade version of `uses_allocator_construction_args `. Thoughts?